# Converting variadic template arguments to static constexpr array

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr

```
namespace ct_parser { 
    namespace variadic {
        template <char... Cs>
        struct static_array<char, Cs...>
        {
            static const char value[sizeof...(Cs)];
            static constexpr char val[sizeof...(Cs)] = { Cs... };
        };

        template <char... Cs>
        const char static_array<char, Cs...>::value[sizeof...(Cs)] = { Cs... };
```

Later...

```
    const char * buf3 = ct_parser::variadic::static_array<char, 'a', 'b'>::value; // OK
    const char * buf4 = ct_parser::variadic::static_array<char, 'a', 'b'>::val; // NOT OK
```

Could anyone explain to me why calling `buf3` compiles just finely, but, once called, `buf4` gives a compilation error, namely:

`Undefined reference to ct_parser::variadic::static_array<char, char(97), char(98)>::val`

(I made use of template specialization, so that I do not have to cast type `char` to itself.

EDIT: Declaring the static member `val` to be `inline` fixes the problem if a compiler supporting C++17 is being used.

Comment: I'm getting the opposite result: undefined reference to `value`. In any case, if your compiler is new enough, try making both variables `inline`.

Comment: This does fix the problem if I use a compiler supporting C++17 - Thank you. However, I'm now wondering whether there's also a fix for a compiler that does not support C++17.

Comment: Before C++17, you need to provide a definition at namespace scope (without initializer). See [cppreference.com on constant static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members).